# Nativescript RadListView StaggeredLayout Issue

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a Nativescript Angular project where I am using RadListView trying to use the staggered layout. It works fine on Android but on iOS there is a spacing issue that I cannot figure out what is causing it.

[image]
[image]

**HTML**

```
<GridLayout class="page page-content" rows="*">
        <GridLayout margin="10">
                <RadListView height="100%" [items]="dataItems">
                        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item" backgroundColor="transparent">
                                <StackLayout rows="auto, auto" borderWidth="1" borderColor="#ccc" margin="10">
                                        <Label class="h3" [text]="item.name"></Label>
                                        <Label class="descriptionLabel" [text]="item.description" textWrap="true"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                        </ng-template>
                        <ListViewStaggeredLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" spanCount="2"></ListViewStaggeredLayout>
                </RadListView>
        </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

**TypeScript**

```
dataItems = [{name: "Item 1", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."},
                 {name: "Item 2", description: "Maecenas ac massa eu odio porta efficitur at non leo"}, 
                 {name: "Item 3", description: "Nunc vitae tortor sodales, varius magna quis, faucibus justo."},
                 {name: "Item 4", description: "In finibus sem"},
                 {name: "Item 5", description: "Duis sed sem porttitor"}, 
                 {name: "Item 6", description: "Blandit est vel, viverra nisi."},
                 {name: "Item 7", description: "Etiam at nisl ultricies, consectetur libero non, iaculis est."},
                 {name: "Item 8", description: "Curabitur at lorem"}, 
                 {name: "Item 9", description: "Non lectus tempus congue ultricies eget tellus."},
                 {name: "Item 10", description: "In sed dolor sit amet velit tempus iaculis."},
                 {name: "Item 11", description: "Duis dictum nunc in neque"},
                 {name: "Item 12", description: "Mauris dignissim mi sit amet nulla tristique, id posuere urna volutpat mauris gravida purus."},
                 {name: "Item 13", description: "Etiam accumsan sapien eget eros convallis porttitor."}, 
                 {name: "Item 14", description: "Vivamus ac arcu"},
                 {name: "Item 15", description: "Vestibulum at elit eget sapien fringilla"},
                 {name: "Item 16", description: "Maecenas tempus enim et velit bibendum, eu consequat erat volutpat."}];
```

Comment: Try with giving height and width for StackLayout

Comment: What if I don't want to apply a fixed height? That's sort of the point of the staggered layout is that height varies with each item.

Comment: try giving height 100% as ios does not allow autolayout.

Comment: It makes the problem worse. It makes each item the height of the screen.

Comment: use itemHeight in ListViewStaggeredLayout  <ListViewStaggeredLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" itemHeight="100" spanCount="2"></ListViewStaggeredLayout>

Comment: Also try giving background color to StackLayout and see if Margin is the culprit here.

Comment: itemHeight="100" sets the height to fixed height for every item.

Comment: Hi Karl Schmaltz, I tested your code with https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/listview/app/examples/item-layouts/listview-item-layouts-staggered.component.html, however, the RadListView was rendered in the same way on both platforms. The Only change I have made is to remove `class="page page-content"` from the main GridLayout. Can you check if those CSS classes are responsible for the `spacing issue`.

Comment: No difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Here is a project recreating the problem. https://github.com/keerl/tab-list-view-problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my end either with or without the extra GridLayouts. At least in my opinion those layouts are not required actually. Here is the [link to Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=74B2Aa).